# OSGI and cloning a service

Tags: osgi

I need to register multiple services from one bundle, I think I cannot use service factory because I have only one bundle that consumes services
put in another way, I have a bundle which represent a physical device(e.g temperature sensor) ,since I have multiple physical device (e.g 10 temperature sensors, each has a unique ID) then I need to have multiple (10) instances of my service from the same bundle, How can I do that ?

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question and add more detail. For example what do you mean by "cloning" the service?

Comment: I meant registering same service multiple times, for example I have a bundle which represent a physical device ,since I have multiple physical device then I need to have multiple instance of same service.. if I rephrase my question,, I have ten temperature sensor, each has a unique id , How I can register 10 instance of the bundle that represent the temperature sensor

Comment: Thanks I will try to answer this now. It would be best for you to edit your original question to add this additional detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple instances of the service can be registered simply through repeated calls to `context.registerService()`. Each registration can carry a distinct set of properties, for example:

```
Properties props1 = new Properties();
props1.put("my_id", "ID1");
context.registerService(Foo.class.getName(), new FooImpl(), props1);
// ...
Properties props2 = new Properties();
props2.put("my_id", "ID2");
context.registerService(Foo.class.getName(), new FooImpl(), props2);
// ...
```

(Note a terminology quibble that may save you some confusion. Bundles do not register *themselves* as services. They create Objects and register those as service. A bundle is a deployment unit or a container for executable code. Bundles can register zero to many services, and/or consume the services registered by other bundles.)